# Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. for new WC_Product_Variable() with variation id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have setup a fresh copy of WordPress on version 4.9.7 and WooCommerce 3.4.4

I have created a Variable product which has the following variations:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the variation IDs are 6, 7, 8 and 9.

However, if I try to do the following:

```
$v = new WC_Product_Variable( 6 );
```

Then I get this nasty error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(156): WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Product_Variable))
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(133): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Product_Variable))
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/functions.php(592): WC_Product->__construct(6)
#3 /var/www/html/wp-settings.php(426): include('/var/www/html/w...')
#4 /var/www/html/wp-config.php(89): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#5 /var/www/html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#6 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#7 /var/www/html/wp-admin/post.php(12): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 149
```

I tried to get around this by doing

```
$product_id = 5;
$_product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$variations = $_product->get_available_variations();
// $variations = array(0) { }
```

But $variations comes back an empty array.

Any help is appreciated as I've hit a brick wall.

Comment: 6 is a product variation NOT a product variable!

Comment: Ah, I see. so I need to be using WC_Product_Variation. Thank you for the outside perspective. Good day.

Comment: `$v = wc_get_product( 6 );` will work too for any product type…